# clang (LLVM) inline assembly - multiple constraints with useless spills / reloads

Tags: gcc, assembly, clang, x86-64, inline-assembly

**clang / gcc** : Some inline assembly operands can be satisfied with multiple constraints, e.g., `"rm"`, when an operand can be satisfied with a register or memory location. As an example, the 64 x 64 = 128 bit multiply:

```
__asm__ ("mulq %q3" : "=a" (rl), "=d" (rh) : "%0" (x), "rm" (y) : "cc")
```

The generated code appears to choose a memory constraint for argument `3`, which would be fine if we were register starved, to avoid a spill. Obviously there's less register pressure on x86-64 than on IA32. However, the assembly snippet generated (by **clang**) is:

```
    movq    %rcx, -8(%rbp)
    ## InlineAsm Start
    mulq -8(%rbp)
    ## InlineAsm End
```

Choosing a memory constraint is clearly pointless! Changing the constraint to: `"r" (y)`, however (forcing a register) we get:

```
    ## InlineAsm Start
    mulq %rcx
    ## InlineAsm End
```

as expected. These results are for clang / LLVM 3.2 (current Xcode release). The first question: **Why would clang select the less efficient constraint in this case?**

Secondly, there is the less widely used, comma-separated, [multiple alternative constraint](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Multi_002dAlternative.html#Multi_002dAlternative) syntax:
`"r,m" (y)`, which *should* evaluate the costs of each alternative, and choose the one that results in less copying. This appears to work, *but clang simply chooses the first* - as evidenced by: `"m,r" (y)`

---

I could simply drop the `"m"` alternative constraints, but this doesn't express the range of possible legal operands. This brings me to the second question: **Have these issues been resolved or at least acknowledged in 3.3?** I've tried looking through LLVM dev archives, but I'd rather solicit some answers before unnecessarily restricting constraints further, or joining project discussions, etc.

Comment: Does enabling optimization have an effect?

Comment: @bames53 - none at all. `-O0` .. `-O3` all yield the same expansion.

Comment: Your best bet for an answer is probably to report the bug in the llvm bug tracker.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had [a response on the cfe-dev](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2013-June/029998.html) (clang front end developers' list) from one of the developers:

> LLVM currently always spills "rm" constraints in order to simplify the
>   handling of inline asm in the backend (you can ask on llvmdev if you want
>   details).  I don't know of any plans to fix this in the near future.

So it's clearly a 'known' issue. One of the goals of clang is to correctly handle gcc's inline assembly syntax, amongst other extensions, which it does in this case - just not very efficiently. In short, this isn't a bug, per se.

---

Since this isn't a bug, I'm going to continue with the `"r,m"` constraint syntax. I figure that this is the best compromise for now. `gcc` will choose the best - presumably a register where possible - and `clang` will force the use of a register by ignoring further options after the comma. If nothing else, it still preserves the *semantic intent* of the assembly statement, i.e., describing *possible* constraints, even if they are ignored.

---

**A final note (20130715) :** This particular example will not compile using the `"r,m"` constraint in a single position - we would have to supply an alternative constraint match for each, e.g.,

```
: "=a,a" (rl), "=d,d" (rh) : "%0,0" (x), "r,m" (y)
```

This is *required* for multiple alternative constraints with GCC. But we're getting into territory where GCC has been known to exhibit bugs in the past - whether or not this is true as of **4.8.1**, I don't know. Clang works *without* the alternatives in the other constraints, which is incompatible with GCC syntax, and must therefore be considered a bug.

If performance is critical, use `"r"`, otherwise, stick with `"rm"` and maybe clang will address this in the future, even as it benefits GCC.

Comment: There does seem to be an open bug about this: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20197

Comment: I'm getting spills on clang with `"r,m"` (or `"ir,m"` in my case). "Solved" it by doing `#if __clang__` and then just not giving calng the `m` option. It ends up loading into a register where gcc would smartly use a memory operand, but that's better for me than spilling registers unnecessarily.

Comment: Here's a demonstration of the behavior: https://godbolt.org/z/xfTYTeqcr. Thanks for sharing your answer. I found it useful.